# Sweetalert getting closed automatically

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, sweetalert

I'm using sweet alert in my project but it's getting closed within seconds

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

```
<script>
        function deleteContact(cid){
            
            swal({
                  title: "Are you sure?",
                  text: "You want to delete this contact?",
                  icon: "warning",
                  buttons: true,
                  dangerMode: true,
                  timer: 5000, 
                })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                  if (willDelete) {
                    /* swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                      icon: "success",
                    }); */
                    window.location="/user/delete/"+cid;
                  } else {
                    swal("Your contact is safe!");
                  }
                });
        }   
    </script>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deleteContact() function is being called here in below delete button-

<a href="" th:onclick="|deleteContact(${c.cId})|"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash text-danger" title="Delete"></i></a>
```

Comment: you have a timer of 5 seconds on your config, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

remove the "timer: 5000," from your swal config

Comment: Thanks, I replaced anchor tag "<a></a>" with button tag "<button></button>" & it's working now.